# Properties of a reflection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations, reflection

If you are given a transformation matrix, how do you check if it represents a reflection quickly? Or if it represents rotation? What is uniq about them that I can easily spot(it doesn't need to be easy).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by reflections and rotations? As far as I know there is some ambiguity in these terms. Also, I'd like to recommend you to read this https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A *reflection* has a single $-1$ eigenvalue and all the other eigenvalues are $1$, so there's a fixed hyperplane (the $1$-eigenspace) and a complimentary orthogonal direction spanned by the reflecting $(-1)$-eigenvector.

Comment: Rotation is not generally used outside of $\mathbb{R}^2$ without clarifying the meaning. Is it a literal rotation (a pair of orthogonal eigenvectors that span the "rotation plane" with unit complex conjugate eigenvalues, with all remaining $1$-eigenspace of codimension $2$) or an [orthogonal matrix](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Orthogonal_matrix) or perhaps a *proper* orthogonal matrix (orientation-preserving, hence $\det = 1$)?

Comment: @Sammy "Rotation" is typically used to refer to an element of $SO(n)$

Comment: @Need One relatively quick condition to check is that $A$ is a reflection if $A = A^\top$ and $A^2 = I$.